# How to deduce function type in SML(fun foo f=f 5;)

Tags: sml

I have a foo function defined as follows

```
fun foo f = f 5;
```

How to deduce the function type?

Answer (score 2):

We can see that `f` must be a function. We also see, that f takes an integer as an input, since we call `f 5`. Therefore `f` must have type `int -> 'a`.

`foo` then takes an `int -> 'a`, and produces an `'a`, yielding: `foo : (int -> 'a) -> 'a`.

Answer (score 0):

SML uses a variant of this algorithm to do type inference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner